# How to use WebSocketServlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty

The WebSocketServlet API in Tomcat seems to be deprecated.
Now I have been trying whether Jetty can be used with Tomcat to replace the WebSocket functionality, but couldn't get it to work.

Is there any way to use WebSockets with Tomcat? ( Without using the deprecated classes )

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

Comment: It's deprecated because you need to use [JSR-356](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm). Here is [a tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api).